# PHP 5.3 to PHP7 - Undefined class constant 'self::MYCONST'

Tags: php, migration, php-7, class-constants

I have a project running on PHP 5.3.21 that I am trying to migrate to PHP 7.0. 
The project uses a lot the structure as in the example below:

```
<?php
class foo {
    protected $_const = self::MYCONST;
}

class boo extends foo {
    const MYCONST = "test";

    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->_const.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
new boo();
```

The expected result is printing "test", and it works perfectly on 5.3, but on 7.0 I get

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant
>   'self::MYCONST'

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Just saying. Shouldn't the constant be defined in the parent class?

Comment: Can't even apply late static binding, as that is a run-time evaluation, and constant definitions can only be compile time

Comment: The parent class has no knowledge (nor should it have) about anything defined in the child class.

Comment: I was almost sure this shoudn't work, but it does :P http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43462e3581f9778e0bce57d1351ee9aa32f51e90

Comment: @mleko - I think we have different definitions of "working" :-) That link produces: _"Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'self::MYCONST' in ..."_

Comment: You need to set `$this->_const` in the `boo` constructor, because only `boo` knows that `foo` exists; `foo` doesn't know about `boo`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson run this on 5.3, check link I provided

Comment: Funny enough it works on 5.3.. Weird

Comment: @mleko - Ah. Wow, then it works. I guess what we can take from that is that PHP has become more structured and "correct" lately :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to transfer the constants to the parent classes in your project